# Question re: defining exponential function

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

On page 212 of "Burn Math Class," we're presented with the following line of reasoning (note that $x$ and $y$ are simply two numbers and neither is a function of the other):

1) Define a function by the behavior $f(x + y) = f(x) \cdot f(y)$

2) We can deduce that $f(0) = 1 $

3) We differentiate with respect to y and get $f'(x + y) = f'(y) \cdot f(x)$

4) By setting $y=0$ in line #3 we find: $f'(x) = f'(0) \cdot f(x)$

Here are my questions (I sent these to the author directly, but got no reply):

> A) In differentiating the equation (step #3 above) the author mentions we need to make use of two facts: $\frac{dx}{dy} = 0$ and $\frac{d(x + y)}{dy} = 1$. I can't see where the second expression gets used, as I simply apply the product rule to get the derivative. What am I missing?
>
> B) Because $\frac{dx}{dy} = 0$, it seems like the derivative in line #4 would always equal $0$. Here's why:

i) $\frac d{dy} [f(x+y)] = f(x) \frac d{dy} [f(y)]$

ii) With $y=0$ this simplifies to $\frac d{dy} [f(x)] = f(x) \cdot \frac d{dy} [f(0)]$

iii) By the chain rule, $\frac d{dy} [f(x)] = \frac {df(x)}{dy} \cdot \frac{dx}{dx} = \frac{df(x)}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{dy} = \frac {df(x)}{dx} \cdot 0 = 0$. Clearly something is wrong here, but I can't see what.

> C) We conclude the section by noting that the expression $f'(x) = f'(0) * f(x)$ means this function's derivative is almost equal to its first derivative. But we seem to have glossed over the fact that we differentiated with respect to $y$, not $x$ (such is the drawback of prime notation). In other words, what we really have is $\frac d{dy} [f(x)] = f(x) *\cdot \frac d{dy} [f(0)]$. Maybe this doesn't matter because $x$ and $y$ are just arbitrary numbers, but something doesn't quite sit right with me.

I apologize for the long post - hopefully someone has the patience and insight to help answer my questions.

Edit: here's a link to the page in question - reading the original text might help clarify my questions. https://ibb.co/kePfiv

Comment: Basically, I believe (s)he wants $x$ and $y$ to be independent.

Comment: How can you apply the product rule if you don't know what df(x)/dy is?  You us need both these equations and the chain rule to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

A) $\frac{df(x+y)}{dy} = \frac{df(x)f(y)}{dy}$

$= \frac{df(x)}{dy}f(y) + f(x)f'(y)$ but we don't know what $ \frac{df(x)}{dy}$ is unless we use the chain rule.  $\frac{df(x)}{dy} = f'(x)*\frac{dx}{dy} = f'(x)*0 = 0$. so $\frac{df(x+y)}{dy}= f(x)f'(y)$.  But we don't know that $\frac{df(x+y)}{dy}= f'(x+y)$.

Using the chain rule was get $\frac{df(x+y)}{dy} = f'(x+y)\frac{d(x+y)}{dy} = f'(x+y)*1= f'(x+y)$.

B) You can't take a derivative in terms of a variable when the variable is fixed.  That's simply a meaningless concept.

C) A derivative is a derivative.  If $f'(z) = g(z)$ then $f'(pinkhonkhonk) = g(pinkhonkhonk)$ it doesn't matter what variable label we used to derive it.  We did some fancy footwork to discover that if $f$ has the property that $f(a+b) = f(a)f(b)$ then $f$ also has the very weird property that $f'(a+b)=f'(b+a)= f(a)f'(b)=f(b)f'(a)$.  We found out that result but differentiating $f(x+y)$ in terms of $y$ but the result is one about $f$ and $f'$ for any values.

You state "what we really have is $\frac d{dy} [f(x)] = f(x) *\cdot \frac d{dy} [f(0)]$".  Not quite.  What we really have is $\frac d{d(x+y)} [f(x+y)]_{x+y = x}*\frac{d{x+y}}{dy}_{y=0} = f(x) *\cdot \frac d{dy} [f(y)]_{y=0}$

And as

$\frac d{d(x+y)} [f(x+y)]_{x+y = x} = f'(x+y)_{x+y=x} = f'(x)$.

$\frac{d{x+y}}{dx}_{y=0} = 1_{y=0} = 1$

$\frac d{dy} [f(y)]_{y=0}=f'(y)_{y=0} = f'(0)$.

That is nothing more or less than $f'(x) = f'(0)f(x)$

Comment: Thanks very much. At the risk of abusing your charity, would you mind taking a quick look at the original text? I added a link to it at the end of my original post. I wonder if my questions (and your answers) will shine in a different light once you've seen the actual text.

Comment: It was very hard to read that resolution.  I think my interpretation remains the same.  I'll try reading it some more.

Comment: After the line staring "You state..." why do you switch to differentiating wrt x instead of y on the LHS of the equation? (That is, you have d(x+y)/dx with y=0). Per the text, we are differentiating with respect to y.

Comment: That was just a typo.

Comment: Thanks - so in the concluding equation, is it true that f'(x) = df/dx? Or would that be incorrect? I think I'm being thrown off by the interplay between prime notation and dy/dx notation...

Comment: It's just notation. If f is a single variable function then f' is the derivative in regards to that variable. It doesn't matter what you label the variable.  This has nothing to do with derivatives.  It'd be the same if we simply talked of the function g (x)=x^2 +7.  And the function g (w)=w^2+7.  They are the same function as they are the same mapping.  The label x or w doesn't mean anything.  So yes, df (x)/dx =f'(x).   The d notation let's us do do things in respect of other variables.  Let g(x)=f (x+5). We can't express g'(x) without defining g.  But with d notation we can do d f (x+5)/dx.